# iOS 10 beta - TouchID login does not pop up pin pad

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

In iOS 9.x, after 5 (3 then 2) attempts at Biometric Login, iOS automatically pops up a default pin code screen. This doesn't happen in iOS 10 Beta.  It simply fails the "canEvaluatePolicy" check instead. Does anyone know if this is just a bug in iOS 10 Beta or do I have to add the code to support pin code screen somehow?

Here's the code:

```
-(void)touchTester {
    LAContext *myContext = [[[LAContext alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSError *authError = nil;

    NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Sign on with TouchID\u00AE or enter password.";
    myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = @"Enter Password";

    self.touchIdActive = NO;
    if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
        [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                            reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                if (success) {
                                    self.touchIdActive = YES;
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                        NSLog(@"Launching loginUser");
                                        [self loginUser:YES];
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    self.touchIdActive = NO;

                                    NSString * errMsg = error.localizedDescription;
                                    if (![errMsg isEqualToString:@"Canceled by user."]) {
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                                message:errMsg
                                                                                               delegate:self
                                                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                            [alertView show];
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }];
    } else {
        // This is where we go after lockout in iOS 10
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:authError.localizedDescription
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What iOS Beta 10 you have. I've got 7. But every Beta of iOS10 worked me this summer. Please describe your situation a bit more wide.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Well I just loaded it up today.  Phone calls it 10. (14A5345a). Basically I added TouchID support to my app.  It has an "automatic" feature where if you fail to biometrically authenticate three times in a row it returns an "Automatic retry limit exceeded." error.  If you try again and you fail to biometrical authenticate 2 more times iOS 10 returns a "Biometry is locked out." error.  In iOS 9 you get a key pad in the latter case which allows you to re-enter your TouchID pin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

show the Code:

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = [InternationalControl localStringByKey:@"gesture_forget"];
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = [InternationalControl localStringByKey:@"touchHome"];

BOOL isOK = [myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError];
if (isOK) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@" 查看是什么情况 %@",error);
            TouchType typeState = TouchTypeOther;
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"解锁成功");
            } else {
                if(error.code == -8){
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
                        myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = [InternationalControl localStringByKey:@"gesture_forget"];
                        NSError *authError = nil;
                        NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = [InternationalControl localStringByKey:@"touchHome"];
                        BOOL isOK = [myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&authError];
                        if (isOK) {
                            [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                                reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@" 查看是什么情况 %@",error);
                                }];
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }];
} else {

    if(authError.code == -8){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
            myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = [InternationalControl localStringByKey:@"gesture_forget"];
            NSError *authError = nil;
            NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = [InternationalControl localStringByKey:@"touchHome"];
            BOOL isOK = [myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&authError];
            if (isOK) {
                [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                    reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@" 查看是什么情况 %@",error);
                    }];
            }
        });
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",authError);
}
```